# Can not render After Effects CC project as mp4 / h.264 any more?

Tags: cc-2014

I've made a 2 minute video on After Effects CC.
There is no option to save using depreciated formats.
Other answers suggest going to:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> output -> enable Show Deprecated Formats
```

however I can't see this checkbox and I assume it has been removed completely now!

All I am looking to do is upload to YouTube but the rendered AVI video is 20GB!
If I set composition resolution to half, and the output also to half the original size I can save it as 5GB but this will still take over 3/4 hours to upload on my connection.

What settings should I be using to get a decent quality video at a small size so I can upload to YouTube??  I don't need HD, but I would like it to be somewhat good quality.

I am also not too familiar with some of the other formats, so I'm a bit lost atm.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  I have migrated your question to another stack site that might be better suited.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to ask so I had searched for previous questions re AE-CC and ended up on the other site

Answer (score 8):

All Adobe video products are intended to target consumer formats through Adobe Media Encoder since CC 2014, After Effects has almost only intermediate formats now in its internal renderer (which is essentially the exact same thing as the one in AME).

Instead of clicking on "Add to Render Queue" you click on "Add to Media Encoder Queue" and in AME you will have all the formats you had before and even a few more.

This has the advantage that you can continue working on your project while AME is rendering your composition. No need anymore for a background render plugin.

Comment: +1. Adobe Media Encoder is great and I use it on a regular basis for exporting from After Effects and Premiere Pro. Another huge plus for using AME is the ability to send large numbers of things to be exported and allowing them to essentially be batch processed in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a local AVI to .h264 or any other available codec using a program like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) or [AVC](http://www.any-video-converter.com/download/), or if you're comfortable at the command line, straight [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).